# Conditional replace with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df like this one:

```
ID VAL
1  4
2  2
3  1
1  4
2  3
3  3
```

What I would like is that if ID is higher or equal to ID3 then ID3 should be a random value between 5 and 6. So I would get a result like:

```
ID VAL
1  4
2  2
3  5
1  4
2  3
3  6
```

The df is actually 6000 lines long so I want to come up with a way to iterate and solve if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: So in your example, last two lines. IF ID 2 was val 4 instead of 3, then ID3 val 3 stays the same?

Comment: What’s _ID3_? All I see is _ID_.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment, you want change only ID=3 where `VAL` is less than `VAL` of ID=2. You only need another mask to check ID=3 less than ID=2 by using `diff`

```
m = df.ID.eq(3)
m1 = df.VAL.diff().le(0)
df.loc[m & m1, 'VAL'] = np.random.choice([5, 6], size=(m & m1).sum())

Out[549]:
   ID  VAL
0   1    4
1   2    2
2   3    6
3   1    4
4   2    3
5   3    5
```

If you don't want repeating values, specify option `replace=False`

```
m = df.ID.eq(3)
m1 = df.VAL.diff().le(0)
df.loc[m & m1, 'VAL'] = np.random.choice([5, 6], size=(m & m1).sum(), replace=False)
```

Comment: This is not working as it will replace al values for 3 and I only want to replace IF the VAL for ID = 2 is higher than the VAL for ID = 3.

Comment: Could you edit the sample to include the case where it shouldn't replace on `ID=3`?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
import random
what = (df['ID'] ==3 ) & ((df['VAL'] <= df['VAL'].shift()))
df['new_col'] = what
df.loc[df['new_col'] == True, 'VAL'] = random.randint(5,6)
```

```
   ID  VAL  new_col
0   1    4    False
1   2    2    False
2   3    6     True
3   1    4    False
4   2    3    False
5   3    6     True
```

you can drop new_col

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the VAL where ID is greater or equal than 3 with a random choose between 5 and 6

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random


sample_data = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                            'VAL': [4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3]})

# To generate the same pseudo random numbers
random.seed(51)

sample_data['VAL'] = np.where(sample_data['ID']>=3, random.choice([5, 6]), sample_data['VAL'])
```